# JavaScript page causes computer to become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am completely new to JavaScript so please be patient with me

I have been following a tutorial to display images from a folder in JavaScript but when I add the script that iterates it causes the computer viewing the page to lock up completely

The following in inside my  tags:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var graphics_context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var currentpage = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if ((e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") && !rightPressed) {
        rightPressed = true;
        currentpage++;
    } 
    else if ((e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") && !leftPressed) {
        leftPressed = true;
        currentpage--;
    }
}
        
function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
    } 
    else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}
        
function draw() {
    var img = new Array();
            
    for(let i = 0; true; i++) {
        try {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = "img/" + i + ".jpg"; 
            img[i] = image;
        } 
        catch(err) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if(currentpage <= 0)
        currentpage = 0;

    if(currentpage >= img.length)
        currentpage = img.length - 1;

    ctx.drawImage(img[currentpage], 0, 0, 800, 800);
}
        
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

I do realise that reading from a folder in a loop is incredibly inefficient but I really don't see how it would cause my entire PC to lock up (it is a separate PC to the one running the page)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I believe your are filling the memory to quickly with setInterval, how long does it take for the page to become unresponsive?

Comment: JavaScript cannot read folders. Also, you're creating 100 infinite loops per second, each creating thousands of Image objects.

Comment: What possible real life scenario do you need to launch an infinite loop every 10 milliseconds to read images for?

Comment: @EugenSunic pretty much instant

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I have a backend which is writing and editing these images extremely quickly

Comment: Do the old images change? Or does the server keep adding new images? In that case, how about just a `setInterval` that checks if new images are present by saving the last image index each time. And in all cases, 10 milliseconds is too small to be perceived by anyone, I think 100 milliseconds is still pretty fast and much more efficient.

Comment: @ChrisG Well I am reading all files named n.jpg from the folder img/ which only contains those files if that's a more accurate description. Anyway I need this kinda of read speed

Comment: `try..catch` doesn't catch a resource loading error, this leads to an infinite loop. You've to set an `onerror` handler to the image itself (`image` has to be declared with `let`), or rather re-think the entire logic ...

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi It edits the old images - I will try a slower speed

Comment: @Teemu Is there any way to check if a file exists then?

Comment: There is, but it's a time-consuming operation, `image.onerror` is much faster.

Comment: Is the amount of the images in the folder changing? If you'd know beforehand, how many images there is in the folder, you could use that constant number to limit the loop. Also, images are usually cached, they're loaded from the server once only, an edited image wouldn't be seen on the client.